# count using subqueries in T-sql

Tags: t-sql

The following is my query.  I need to get the count of the doctor's visits for each patient in the query.  The count isn't right and it's printing 2 rows for each patient.

```
 SELECT 
     pf.PatientId
    , p.Visit
    , pf.first
    , pf.last
    , df.first
    , df.last
     , doc.reconcile_status
     , doc.orderid
     , count(p.visit)


  FROM [CentricityPS].[dbo].[PatientVisit] p
    , [CentricityPS].[dbo].[document] doc
    , [CentricityPS].[dbo].[Patientprofile] pf
    , [CentricityPS].[dbo].[doctorfacility] df

  where  df.pvid in ('1507023132004420', '1725527248154950', '1406648461000690')
     and  p.doctorid = df.DoctorFacilityId
     and p.patientprofileid = pf.patientprofileid
    and pf.pid = doc.pid
    and pf.patientstatusmid = '-900'
    and pf.PatientProfileId = p.PatientProfileId
--  and pf.PatientId = '8145' 
  -- and p.visit >= '2016-01-01' and p.visit <= '2016-07-01'
   and not exists (select * from [CentricityPS].[dbo].[PatientVisit] p 
   where  (p.visit > '2013-01-01' and p.visit < = '2016-01-01')

     and p.patientprofileid = pf.patientprofileid and pf.patientstatusmid not in (-901)  ) 
      and not exists (select * from [CentricityPS].[dbo].[PatientVisit] p 
   where  p.visit <= '2013-01-01' 
     and p.patientprofileid = pf.patientprofileid and pf.patientstatusmid not in (-901) ) 
--     and pf.patientid = '100293'
group by df.DoctorFacilityId, pf.PatientId, p.visit, pf.first, pf.last, df.first, df.last, doc.RECONCILE_STATUS, doc.ORDERID, p.PatientProfileId
 order by df.doctorfacilityid, pf.patientid, p.visit desc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Help!!!

Comment: except for basic syntax errors, queries by themselves are USELESS for figuring out problems, without accompanying sample data and table structures.

Comment: please check this [LINK o improve the question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping on too many fields.  If you just need the count of doctor's visits for each patient, only SELECT PatientProfile fields along with count(p.visit) and just include the same PatientProfile fields in the GROUP BY.